# PermissionSetGroups in Unlocked Packages

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package

Is there any restriction to PermissionSetGroups in Unlocked Packages?

```
saulo_XXXXX@SAULOS-MBP commerciallending % sfdx force:package:version:create \
--package "XXXXXXXX" \
--path force-app \
--installationkey "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
--wait 10 \
--targetdevhubusername XXXXXXXX-devhub
```

Result:

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  These entities are not supported: [PermissionSetGroup]
```

The project has only two changes:
A Permission set called "Account_Create";
A Permission set group called "CL_Admin"

Here it is the source code of the project: https://github.com/sauloefo/NsOrg1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Metadata Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/53) is a great resource for checking this type of information.

You'll see that `PermissionSetGroup` has a note for Unlocked Packaging:

> Requires package **without** a namespace.

Looking at your github, it seems you do have a namespace which is why you're getting that error that the entity is not supported.

[image]

Comment: many thanks my friend! Super handy document I didn't know it exists!